# Change global environment to read in numerical order

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I have 22 animals. Each animal has been named as follows: `c(" Shark1", "Shark2", "Shark3", ...)` etc.

I am trying to plot a two category variables against each other do determine the proportion of time each shark spent at separate depths:

```
Sharks<-table(merge$DepthCat, merge$ID2) #Depth category vs. ID


merge$DepthCat[merge$Depth2>200]<-"4"
Sharks<-table(merge$DepthCat, merge$ID2)

plot(t(Sharks), main="", 
     col=c("whitesmoke", "slategray3", "slategray", "slategray4"), 
     ylab="Depth catagory", xlab="Month")
axis(side=4)
```

While the plot works, it is not plotting in numerical order but instead alphabetical therefore I am getting the following graph below.

Does anyone know how to resolve this for the plot? I have research the array method but unsure how it would be implemented here.

[image: Sharks_plot]

Comment: wouldnt just `Sharks<-table(merge$DepthCat, as.numeric(merge$ID2))` work?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide your complete data set, so I generated my own random data. Given that the bar headers derived from `ID2` are sorting lexicographically, I assumed they are stored as characters in your data.frame `merge`, so I generated them thusly.

```
set.seed(2L);
NR <- 300L;
merge <- data.frame(ID2=sample(as.character(1:22),NR,T),Depth2=pmax(0,rnorm(NR,100,50)),stringsAsFactors=F);
merge$DepthCat <- as.character(findInterval(merge$Depth2,c(0,66,133,200)));

str(merge);
## 'data.frame': 300 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ ID2     : chr  "5" "16" "13" "4" ...
##  $ Depth2  : num  148.8 91.5 136.1 57.8 163.9 ...
##  $ DepthCat: chr  "3" "2" "3" "1" ...
```

And sure enough, we can reproduce the problem with this test data:

```
Sharks <- table(merge$DepthCat,merge$ID2);

plot(t(Sharks),main='',col=c('whitesmoke','slategray3','slategray','slategray4'),ylab='Depth category',xlab='Month');
axis(side=4L);
```

[image: plot1]

---

The solution is to coerce the `ID2` vector to numeric so it sorts numerically.

```
merge$ID2 <- as.integer(merge$ID2);

str(merge);
## 'data.frame': 300 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ ID2     : int  5 16 13 4 21 21 3 19 11 13 ...
##  $ Depth2  : num  148.8 91.5 136.1 57.8 163.9 ...
##  $ DepthCat: chr  "3" "2" "3" "1" ...

Sharks <- table(merge$DepthCat,merge$ID2);

plot(t(Sharks),main='',col=c('whitesmoke','slategray3','slategray','slategray4'),ylab='Depth category',xlab='Month');
axis(side=4L);
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: This is perfect, it didn't even cross my mind to check if it was a character (oops)!